# Call image from post on index page?

Tags: posts, functions

I am facing one problem in which i dont understand what I used to call the  image from post in WordPress themes on front page where n numbers of image are show with there description and user can dynamically image change. whatever he wants.

What I write the code in .php file

Comment: Please show us what have you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
 <?php
 while ( have_posts() ): the_post();
    // Display post
    if ( have_posts() ): 
            the_post_thumbnail();     //call image that you set in featured image in each post on right sidebar of admin panel.
            the_content();            //call content
    endif;
 endwhile;
 ?>
```